# OpenCL get_global_id and get_local_id using int vs. size_t?

Tags: opencl

I'm a newbie to OpenCL just trying to get a hang of global and local work sizes. I'm trying to declare a 2D work space in my host code:

```
   size_t local[2]  = {1,16};
   size_t global[2] = {1024, 16};

   // Execute the kernel for execution
   status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue, kernel, 2, NULL,
         global, local, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

In my kernel code, I'm simply trying to print out the thread IDs:

```
   size_t g_x = get_global_id(0);
   size_t g_y = get_global_id(1);
   size_t l_x = get_local_id(0);
   size_t l_y = get_local_id(1);

  printf("Thread (%d, %d, %d, %d)\n", g_x, g_y, l_x, l_y);
```

But, I only get the first dimension to print (here's a sample of output):

```
...
Thread (1016, 0, 50, 0)
Thread (1016, 0, 51, 0)
Thread (1016, 0, 52, 0)
Thread (1016, 0, 53, 0)
Thread (1016, 0, 54, 0)
...
```

Why is this happening? I've played around with dimension sizes but I don't think that's the problem.

EDIT: When I replace **size_t** with **int**, I get the correct print out. But why is this? size_t is simply an unsigned type; I don't see why it would successfully print out the first dimension but not the second?

Comment: could be a driver issue. what does  CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS equal to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `%d` for printing anything that is not an integer. size_t depends on the device you are currently using and could be a `unsigned 64bits`, or `unsigned 32bits`.

Use `%zu` instead.

---

Longer explanation:

The 0s you are seeing is because of print assumes it will receive 4 ints, but you are sending 4 longs.

So, every even number is in reality just getting the upper bits of the previous one, which are 0 in this case.

```
Sent: AAAA0000 BBBB0000 CCCC0000 DDDD0000
Recv: AAAABBBB CCCCDDDD
```